# Adding validation to simple React + Typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hooks

I have kind of an easy problem, but I'm stuck because I do not know TypeScript well (and I need to get to know it very quickly).

I have to add simple validation on submit which will check if a value is not empty.

I have the simplest React form:

```
type FormValues = {
  title: string;
};

function App() {
  const [values, handleChange] = useFormState<FormValues>({
    title: ""
  });

  const handleSubmit = (evt: FormEvent) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("SUBMITTED");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          id="title"
          name="title"
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          value={values.title}
        />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Custom hook to handle form:

```
import { useCallback, useReducer } from "react";

type InputChangeEvent = {
  target: {
    name: string;
    value: string;
  };
};

function useFormState<T extends Record<string, string>>(initialValue: T) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (prevState: T, { name, value }: InputChangeEvent["target"]) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }),
    initialValue
  );

  const handleDispatch = useCallback(
    (evt: InputChangeEvent) => {
      dispatch({
        name: evt.target.name,
        value: evt.target.value
      });
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  return [state, handleDispatch] as const;
}

export default useFormState;
```

Now I'd like to add simple validation on submit and (because of TS) I have no idea how. I've thought about three options:

1. Put the validation logic to the `handleSubmit` method.
2. Put the validation logic inside custom `useFormState` hook.
3. Create another custom hook just to manage validation only.

I tried to handle the first (and I think the worst) solution in this [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-ovg01?file=/src/App.tsx), but as I said the TS types are stronger than me and the code does not work.

Would anyone be so kind and help me with both cases (pick the most correct solution and then, run the code with TS)?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what validation you want to do?

Comment: @jered  Simple validation on submit which will check if value is not empty string.

Comment: Do you want the input to validate at any time it changes (basically in real time as they interact with the form) or only when they click "submit"?

Comment: @jered only when someone click submit.

Comment: You can just use the native validation API offered by the browser. Use `required` on the input fields and then call [`formElement.checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#methods) when submitting the form.

Comment: @Terry sure, I knew that. But solution of my task has to be written in without it, cause this is requirenment and I'd like to display some nice, custom error message.

Comment: The validation API is part of the browser's JS API.

Comment: @Terry I know I know, my bad. I mean I have to use different way to do that, e.g. create custom hook, customize existing hook or smth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach would be to just store the form error value in a React useState variable and render it as necessary.

```
const [error, setError] = React.useState('');

// ...

const handleSubmit = (evt: FormEvent) => {
  evt.preventDefault();

  // This might be the wrong way to check the input value
  // I haven't worked directly with form submit events in a hot minute
  if (!evt.target.value) {
    setError('Title is required');
  }
};

// ...

<input
  id="title"
  name="title"
  onChange={handleChange}
  type="text"
  value={values.title}
  aria-describedby="title-error"
  required
  aria-invalid={!!error}
/>
{error && <strong id="title-error" role="alert">{error}</strong>}
```

Notice that the `aria-describedby`, `required`, `aria-invalid` and `role` attributes are important to enforce semantic relationships between the input and its error, announce the error to screen readers when it appears, and designate the input as "required".

If you had multiple inputs in the form, you can make your `error` value into an object that can store a separate error for each field of your form:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({});

// ...

setErrors(oldErrors => ({...oldErrors, title: "Title is required"}));

// ...


{errors.title && <strong id="title-error" role="alert">{errors.title}</strong>}
```

Another common pattern is to clear an input error when it is modified or "touched" to allow the form to be resubmitted:

```
onChange={(e) => {
  setError(''); // or setErrors(({title: _, ...restErrors}) => restErrors);

  handleChange(e);
}}
```

Note that all of this error handling logic *can* be rolled into your custom hooks for form/input handling in general, but does not have to be.